# get Position from a String value

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xaml, xamarin

i'm using a google maps API to take a place from a searchbar, i store it in a item, now, i need to add to this Item the position, but i don't know how to do it,

C#:

```
search.TextChanged += async (sender, e) =>
        {
            try
            {
                if (DatabaseManager.IsOnline())
                {
                    var searchBar = (SearchBar)sender;
                    var client = new HttpClient();
                    var url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=" + searchBar.Text + "&types=geocode&key=" + API_KEY;
                    var json = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                    var predictionList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GooglePlaceResult>(json);
                    var srcList = new List<string>();


                    foreach (var place in predictionList.predictions)
                    {
                        srcList.Add(place.description);
                    }

                    listView.ItemsSource = srcList;
                    listView.ItemTapped += ListView_ItemTapped;

                    /*var url2 = "urlAPIidon'tknow"+listView.ItemTapped+"otherstuff"+"APIKEY2";
                    var json = await vlient.GetStringAsync(url2);  
                    other to parse it and add to Item
                 */
                }
                else
                {
                    var srcList = new List<string>
                    {
                        "No connection"
                    };
                    listView.ItemsSource = srcList;
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("error", "unknown error", "ok");
            }

        };
```

i have use an auto predict api to take the string but now i need the position of that string, i think of do something(in the comment) to take the string send like url to an other GMaps api(i don't know how) and save the position in 2 variable

Comment: Do you want add the string position to the item?

Comment: no just one position i need to take the position